# Overload 1 of 2, '(associatedClassGetter: ModelClassGetter, foreignKey?: string | undefined): Function', gave the following error

Tags: typescript, tsc, sequelize-typescript

I'm getting this error on build using tsc

> Overload 1 of 2, '(associatedClassGetter: ModelClassGetter,
>   foreignKey?: string | undefined): Function', gave the following error.
>       Argument of type '{ foreignKey: { name: string; unique: string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.   Overload 2 of 2,
>   '(associatedClassGetter: ModelClassGetter, options?: BelongsToOptions
>   | undefined): Function', gave the following error.
>       Type '{ name: string; unique: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string | ForeignKeyOptions | undefined'.
>         Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'unique' does not exist in type 'ForeignKeyOptions'.
>
> 55   @BelongsTo(() => Company, {
>         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 56     foreignKey: { name: "companyId", unique: "email_active_unique" }
>
> ```
> 57   })
> ```

```
 @BeforeCreate
  public static generateId(employee: Employee) {
    employee.id = uuidv4();
  }

  @IsUUID(4)
  @PrimaryKey
  @Unique
  @Column
  public id: string;

  @Column
  name: string;

  @Column({ allowNull: false, unique: "email_active_unique" })
  email: string;

  @Column
  password: string;

  @Column
  valid: boolean;

  @Column
  active: boolean;

  @Column
  creator: boolean;

  @ForeignKey(() => Company)
  @Column({
    allowNull: true,
    field: 'companyId',
  })
  companyId: string;

  @BelongsTo(() => Company, {
    foreignKey: { name: "companyId", unique: "email_active_unique" }
  })
  company: Company;
```

can someone helpe please ?
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: That package.json isn't super helpful, and you haven't provided any code. But, in general, that just means that you're passing the wrong arguments to the function.

Comment: thanks, can you check with the code ?Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar enough with what you're doing to help with that .

Comment: Did you get a solution cant seem to get any with this